# Using NodeJs' Grunt on code that is developed on Windows and built on Linux?

Tags: node.js, gruntjs, cross-platform, phantomjs, mocha.js

How to use nodejs to build a cross platform project?

I develop on Windows, but my codebase builds on a Linux-based CI server. It uses Grunt to build the frontend, and requires several nodejs modules for that.

Nodejs requires modules to be installed locally to the project in order for the to be loaded by grunt.task.loadNpmTasks. The issue with that is that I have to install them from somewhere, either Windows or Linux, and when I do from one it doesn't work on the other.

The list modules my project require are installed locally as follows:

```
npm install connect-livereload --production
npm install time-grunt --production
npm install load-grunt-tasks --production
npm install jshint-stylish --production
npm install load-grunt-tasks --production
npm install grunt-contrib-copy --production
npm install grunt-contrib-concat --production
npm install grunt-contrib-uglify --production
npm install grunt-contrib-compass --production
npm install grunt-contrib-jshint --production
npm install grunt-contrib-cssmin --production
npm install grunt-contrib-connect --production
npm install grunt-contrib-clean --production
npm install grunt-contrib-htmlmin --production
npm install grunt-contrib-imagemin --production
npm install grunt-contrib-watch --production
npm install grunt-rev --production
npm install grunt-usemin --production
npm install grunt-mocha --production
npm install grunt-exec --production
npm install grunt-open --production
npm install grunt-svgmin --production
npm install grunt-concurrent --production
npm install grunt-ember-templates --production
npm install grunt-replace --production
npm install grunt-neuter  --production
```

If I install it from Windows and then run `grunt` on the project folder from Windows still it all works perfectly. If I then check the code into git and build in the linux box, chmod 777 and chown to my user, and run the same `grunt` command. It fails with a lot of errors like these:

```
Running "mocha:all" (mocha) task
Testing: http://localhost:9000/index.html
Fatal error: spawn ENOENT
```

I ran `npm install` and it starts failing with another message:

```
Running "mocha:all" (mocha) task
Testing: http://localhost:9000/index.html

/home/administrator/platform/frontend/node_modules/grunt-contrib-compass/node_modules/tmp/lib/tmp.js:261
  throw err;
        ^
Error: spawn ENOENT
    at errnoException (child_process.js:998:11)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:789:34)
```

Nothing I do makes it work.

So from the Linux box I deleted the whole node_modules directory from my project and rerun the install commands above. All works perfectly on Linux now.

Then I check it into git and checkout in Windows. Then I go to the project folder and run `grunt`, and then it fails with:

```
Running "mocha:all" (mocha) task
Testing: http://localhost:9000/index.html

Running PhantomJS...ERROR
>> 'c:\Users\Edy' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
 0 [ '\'c:\\Users\\Edy\' is not recognized as an internal or external command,\r',
>>   'operable program or batch file.' ]
>> operable program or batch file. 1 [ '\'c:\\Users\\Edy\' is not recognized as an internal or external command,\r',
>>   'operable program or batch file.' ]
Warning: PhantomJS exited unexpectedly with exit code 1. Use --force to continue.
```

Uninstalling phantomjs and installing it locally doesn't help. Installing globally doesn't help either. So the only way to make it work on Windows seems to be deleting the node_modules dir and reinstalling on Windows, which brings me to the first issues on Linux.

Is there a way to use nodejs stuff in a cross platform environment like mine? I cannot believe I'm the first one with such a setup out there hehe

Any tips or help in this is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Many dependencies in node.js use native addons. Native addons are compiled for your specific environment when you `npm install`.

If you're moving between environments, you can `npm rebuild` to rebuild those binaries for the new environment. Or the more lengthy way, remove the `node_modules` folder and `npm install` again.

`Fatal error: spawn ENOENT` means a process node.js is trying to spawn does not exist. A common case when trying to spawn a binary compiled for another environment, the binary it is expecting does not exist.

Comment: Oh man thanks, `npm rebuild` was what I was missing... worked like a charm!